# canvas - drawing animated fur like grass with wind and cursor input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I modified a very complicated animated grass example found here and checked a few other examples. I want to make something very similar to this but less complicated code. safari is on its knees trying to render this... also I had to use css transforms to get it to hang from the top of the browser window as desired.

http://yak.is/hairy/

if someone could just explain the basics. I'm lost trying to comprehend the code I hacked.

here's another one I tried:

http://yak.is/hairy/2.html

the shape isn't very hair-like at all, but I do like the simplicity and the cursor input.

basically:

need to draw a realistic-looking amount of hair/fur across the top of the screen (updating canvas width to window width and drawing the correct density of lines) and give them a natural-looking automatic "sway" in the wind.

each line will bend a little bit from cursor input.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MJjHz/

Comment: this is a little overly simplified. note the 2nd example I posted.

Comment: Yep--it's simple, but it illustrates the principles you'll need for your more complex requirements.